# remove quickly several managedObjectContext stored in a NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios

```
for (NSManagedObject *toDelete in array) {
    [moc deleteObject:toDelete];
}
```

is the first writting equivalent to the second one :

```
[array makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(deleteObject:) withObject:moc];
```

and if not, what would be the correct way for the second writting ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are different statements. The latter is equivalent to this:

```
for (NSManagedObject *toDelete in array) {
  [toDelete deleteObject:moc];
}
```

The former is correct and is generally what you should use.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for answering.